# UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have an UICollection View i am using the peek and pop method to look into it normally it works fine but if i use peek and pop i get the error

The code for the collection view class

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    AppsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

                 cell.titleLabel.text = @"TwitClient";

                cell.iconimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitclient"];
               cell.appsbutton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
               cell.appsbutton.hidden = NO;
               cell.appsbutton.alpha = 0.0;
               cell.phoneImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"app3"];
                cell.descLabel.text = @"TwitClient is an app which helps you find tweets on any subject from around the earth. You can search tweets with or without hashtags";
               UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69, 126, 277, 490)];
                    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"T-2"];
        [cell addSubview:imageView];




    return cell;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This is where 3d touch is implmented

```
- (UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
{
    AppsViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"...."];
        previewingContext.sourceRect = self.appsView.frame;



        return appsvc;

}

- (void)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit
{
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerToCommit animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I dont really know what i have done wrong i have done another collection View like this but no error's